# C# local variable visibility issue

Tags: c#

I'm using an older version of Visual Studio and older framework, nonetheless the code below is very basic and should work as far as I can tell. Please don't trouble yourself with the general usefulness of it, as this is just an experiment. My question is strictly about visibility.

For some reason beyond my understanding, the compiler won't let me use myInt inside the "case (5):" block. It underlines it and says "Use of unassigned local variable 'myInt'". Shouldn't myInt be visible within the entire Foo method since it's declared right at the top? What am I missing?

```
    void Foo()
    {
        int myInt, x, y;
        x = 5;
        y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (i == x)
            {
                myInt = i;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                myInt = 0;
            }
        }

        if (myInt > 0)
        {
            switch (x)
            {
                case (5):
                    {
                        if (y == 0)
                        {
                            y = myInt;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                default: { } break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's _visible_, but it isn't _defined_ - unlike fields, inline ('local') variables aren't automatically assigned with the default value for their type. This is by design.

Comment: Are you sure you don't see it in the line `if (myInt > 0)`? Because that's the first time you reference the value of the unassigned local value.

Answer (score 4):

It's because it's *unassigned*.

The *compiler* does *static-analysis* to pick up these sorts of errors. Even though intuitively it looks like you do assign it in your *for loop*, the compiler doesn't forward iterate the *loop* to prove it, there are too many *degrees of freedom*

[Compiler Error CS0165](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165)

> Use of unassigned local variable 'name'
>
> The C# compiler doesn't allow the use of uninitialized variables. If
>   the compiler detects the use of a variable that might not have been
>   initialized, it generates compiler error CS0165. For more information, see 
>   Fields. **This error is generated when the compiler encounters a
>   construct that might result in the use of an unassigned variable, even
>   if your particular code does not**. This avoids the necessity of overly
>   complex rules for definite assignment.

Just assign it when you create it:

```
int myInt = 0
```

Comment: @umpersand if you assign it at the top, the problem goes away , https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sj8mRU

Comment: @umpersand Also if you initially assign it to 0 you don't need the else in the for loop.

Comment: Ah, that was it, thank you. I'm pretty sure I've tried that earlier and it didn't help, but this time around it did. I must have changed something else in the process.

Comment: The compiler deduces that there is no absolutely certain execution path where myInt is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

try to assign as Michael Randall is suggesting:

```
int myInt = 0;
int x = 5;
int y = 0;
```

This should correct the problem

Comment: There's no value in merely referring to someone else's answer. If you have something substantial to add, please do.